# Adobe flash (AS2): How to make a loop that repeats forever, and that duplicates a movieclip every 5 seconds?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to make a loop that repeats forever and that duplicates a movieclip every 5 seconds. This code

```
 var timer = 0;
countup = function(){
timer++;
if (timer >= 5){
    mc.duplicateMovieClip("mc2"+u, u, {_x:50});
    clearInterval(countupInterval);
}
}
var countupInterval = setInterval(countup,1000);
```

duplicates the movieclip once, but after that the interval stops (because of the clearInterval) and no more duplications happens. If I remove the clearInterval part, the movieclip is duplicated once and the same movieclip repeats after 5 seconds (because of the setInterval part). If anybody has a link to a similar problem or an answer to the problem, I would be very thankfull!

Comment: _"forever"_ is a bad idea. It will crash or freeze the computer. Flash Player only gets _x-amount_ of device RAM assigned to it by OS for each run, so soon device RAM will be full of holding these duplicated MCs. Decide what you want to achieve and set that as limit (_ie:_ 100 copies etc)... PS: Why not just move on to AS3 like the whole world did since 2008? It has a `timer` class. I already forgot AS2 but maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use intervals, it's inaccurate for the calling delay. Use timers and calculate the time by yourself:

```
var timerMC:MovieClip = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("timerMC", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
timerMC.lastTime = getTimer();
timerMC.onEnterFrame = function() {
    var currentTime:Number = getTimer();
    if (currentTime - this.lastTime >= 5000) {
        mc.duplicateMovieClip("mc2"+u, u, {_x:50});
        u++;
        this.lastTime = currentTime;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set and constantly change that **u** variable in your code
and omit the **clearInterval** function. Then, if the **timer** value is greater than 4, set it again to 0.
For example:

```
var timer = 0;
var u = 0;
var x = 50;
countup = function(){
    timer++;    
    if (timer > 4){
        timer = 0;
        u++;
        mc.duplicateMovieClip("mc2"+u, u, {_x:x});
        // clearInterval(countupInterval);
        x += 50;
    }
}
var countupInterval = setInterval(countup, 1000);
```